# Apache AH00526 Syntax Error

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I am trying to start my Apache server and keep receiving this error:

AH00526: Syntax error on line 261 of C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf:
Invalid command 'Order', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration.

With some research I found a suggestion of enabling the LoadModule authz_host_module but that did not correct the issue.

The code where the error is:

```
    260  <Files ~ "^\.ht">
    261     Order allow,deny
    262     Deny from all
    263     Satisfy All 
    264  </Files>
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In Apache 2.4 you don't use 2.2 directives.

**Remove all "Order/Deny/Allow/Satisfy" directives** and just use:

> Require

Following your example:

```
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
        Require all denied
</Files>
```

Please see [upgrading](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/upgrading.html) for further changes regarding 2.4 version.